# Ubuntu 16.04 default theme loads first before my custome theme

Tags: unity, themes, startup, appearance

On startup the login screen will be purple instead of my wallpaper and after login the panel color and launcher as well as the wallpaper will be the default purple theme for a second until it loads my custom theme.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Maybe I'm not putting my theme files in the right location?

I put them in /usr/share/themes 
and /usr/share/icons

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Is this because I'm choosing my theme through Unity-tweak-tool? Maybe there is a better place to put my theme files.

Comment: There was a similar question about this in the past. I think it's just the way it is.